# C# Invoke operators in generics on dotnet 2.0

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to implement these on dotnet 2.0.

```
static class Operator
{
    public static object Add(object left, object right)
    {
        //Do something with left + right
    }

    public static object BitwiseAnd(object left, object right)
    {
        //Do something with left | right
    }

    public static object Decrease(object value)
    {
        //Do something with value--
    }

    public static object Divide(object left, object right)
    {
        //Do something with left / right
    }

    public static object Increase(object value)
    {
        //Do something with value++
    }

    public static object Multiply(object left, object right)
    {
        //Do something with left * right
    }

    public static object Subtract(object left, object right)
    {
        //Do something with left - right
    }
}
```

But I'm only know it is possible with [`dynamic` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741%28v=vs.100%29) or `System.Linq.Expressions` on dotnet 4.0.
I want to implement it with framework **dotnet 2.0**.
Is there away to implement it?

Comment: This is unclear, you have shown a bunch of static methods, with no generics.... Are you trying to overload these operators? Also what do mean by invoke?

Comment: If you want to provide Add for any type, you should make it an extension method which is not something you can do before .net framework 3.5. These are not operators, but static methods in your example. They must be static members of the type they are going to operate on.

Comment: What would be the result when you multiply or subtract two Person objects? Or a Person and a Bicycle?

Comment: Would this help? https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/genericoperators.html

Comment: No @HansKeﬆing , [jonskeet.uk/csharp/genericoperators.html](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/genericoperators.html) is not for dotnet 2.0

Answer (score -3):

[Reflection API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) exists since .NET 1.0; it might help you.

Reflection allows you to query for object types, list their methods and properties and invoke them. Unfortunately your question (at the moment) doesn't indicate what precisely you intend to do with the objects, but since you are saying that you could use dynamic in newer .NET versions, reflection looks promising because it allows to achieve everything dynamics do, and more, though the resulting code gets much more verbose.

Comment: This isn't an answer - it's barely even a comment. Please only link to support content you have already put in your answer. You should either flesh this out or delete it.

Comment: @Enigmativity this answers the question as fully as possible, given the amount of information provided by the OP

Comment: If you delete the link it doesn't answer anything. You shouldn't rely on links as your answer. Can you please put the relevant content into your answer?